# Parâmetros Action Mailer com BlueHost Brasil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

Olá, estou tentando enviar notificações na minha aplicação rails, no modo de desenvolvimento. Com o GMAIL, tudo ok, porém não estou conseguindo utilizar com a hospedagem que tenho na BlueHost Brasil.
Já tentei mudar vários parâmetros, atualmente está assim:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.meudominiobluehostbrasil.com.br",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => 'user@dominio',
    :password             => 'pass'
  }
```

Desde já, obrigado pela ajuda de todos!

Comment: Não seria `mail.SEUSITE.com.br`? Nunca usei o bluehost br, mas acho que é a mesma coisa do gringo

Comment: Tentei com MAIL; STMP; Apenas domínio (conforme base de conhecimento, no caso da minha hospedagem, por ser windows). 
"Para a Hospedagem Windows Hosting – E-mails Plesk
*** Para a configuração POP/IMAP
Tipo de Conta: POP/IMAP
Servidor de Entrada de E-mails: o-seu-nome-de-domínio (ex: demomonkey.org)
Servidor de Saída de E-mails: o-seu-nome-de-domínio (ex: demomonkey.org)
Número de Porta do Servidor de Entrada: 110 (caso esteja utilizando POP) / 143 (caso esteja utilizando IMAP)
Número de Porta do Servidor de Saída (SMTP): 587
*Por favor use a Autenticação para o Servidor de Saída de E-mails

Comment: http://kb.br.bluehost.com/configuracao-de-cliente-de-e-mail-popimap/

Comment: O seu é "Para a Hospedagem Windows Hosting – E-mails Plesk" ?

Comment: Exatamente caro amigo. Minha hospedagem é windows.

Comment: Não sei se pode nos ajudar, mas no Gmail, precisei alterar uma configuração, permitindo que aplicativos menos seguros acesse a conta.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Se é windows faça assim: `:address              => "meudominiobluehostbrasil.com.br",`

Comment: Ainda não tentei. Vou fazer o teste. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Retificando o que disse no comentário acima, já havia tentado e tentei novamente. Pode ser alguma restrição da hospedagem, conforme o gmail bloqueia, caso não alteremos a configuração de acesso a apps ?

Comment: A aplicação tem log? Pega o log e coloca aqui pra vermos.

Comment: O log está ativado, porém no arquivo não tem nenhum erro relacionado ao envio do e-mail. Apenas a linha que envia o e-mail. Com o GMAIL, funcionando, as linhas de log ficam exatamente iguais.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o http://kb.br.bluehost.com/configuracao-de-cliente-de-e-mail-popimap/ se você usa

Se o seu serviço é o:

- **Para Serviços de E-mail Grátis / Planos de Hospedagem de E-mail**

  - POP `pop.o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: pop.exemplo.com.br) porta 110
  - IMAP `imap.o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: imap.exemplo.com.br) porta 143
  - SMTP `smtp.o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: smtp.exemplo.com.br) porta 587
- **Para a Hospedagem Linux – E-mails cPanel**

  - POP `pop.o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: mail.exemplo.com.br) porta 110
  - IMAP `imap.o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: mail.exemplo.com.br) porta 143
  - SMTP `smtp.o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: mail.exemplo.com.br) porta 587
- **Para a Hospedagem Windows Hosting – E-mails Plesk**

  - POP `o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: exemplo.com.br) porta 110
  - IMAP `o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: exemplo.com.br) porta 143
  - SMTP `o-seu-nome-de-domínio` (ex: exemplo.com.br) porta 587

No seu caso a hospedagem é Windows então provavelmente é o Emails Plesk que usa.

Deve ficar assim:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "meudominiobluehostbrasil.com.br",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => 'user@dominio',
    :password             => 'pass'
}
```

Comment: Meu serviço: Para a Hospedagem Windows Hosting – E-mails Plesk. 
Amigo, já tentei desta forma. Apenas colei meu último código com smtp , mas já tentei sem SMTP. Inclusive agora. Obrigado pela ajuda. Por favor, se houver mais alguma coisa que posso tentar ou pesquisar coloque aí. Obrigado.

Comment: @user3033607 qual erro a aplicação mostra? Tem algum log no servidor? Tentou configurar no seu computador, tipo pelo outlook?

Comment: Sim, funciona perfeitamente no ThunderBird . Na máquina com a aplicação em desenvolvimento e em outras máquinas. 
O log está ativado, porém no arquivo não tem nenhum erro relacionado ao envio do e-mail. Apenas a linha que envia o e-mail. Com o GMAIL, funcionando, as linhas de log ficam exatamente iguais.

Comment: Mas quando abre a aplicação RoR o que ocorre exatamente? @user3033607

Comment: Aparece a notificação que o e-mail foi enviado, para verificar na caixa de entrada, peço pra reenviar e nada. Com o Gmail, é instantâneo. O suporte da BlueHost Não respondeu.

Comment: @user3033607 então o problema não é com a configuração para o envio, pode ser com a aplicação, me diz como esta a aplicação? Pra que endereço esta tentando enviar

Comment: Bom vamos lá, esta primeira notificação contém o link para alteração de senha do usuário. Ela está funcionando normalmente, todas as funcionalidades.
Estou tentando enviar a notificação para meu e-mail pessoal asselemr@gmail.com .

Comment: Mas qual o remetente que esta usando?

Comment: uma caixa da hospedagem, guilherme.lessa@brasegassistencial.com.br , que funciona no thunderbird, webmail e outra aplicação (PHP).

Comment: @user3033607 o remetente `guilherme.lessa@brasegassistencial.com.br` definido é o mesmo que o usuário do SMTP? Qualquer coisa edita a sua pergunta e adiciona o código RoR (controller, view, etc) que usa pra enviar o e-mail. Outra coisa confere a caixa de SPAM do destinatário

Comment: Vamos lá:
O controller e View utilizado para envio, é da GEM Devise, que utiliza o que estiver definido no action mailer ( logo: guilherme.lessa@brasegassistencial.com.br + Senha ). Creio que não seja problema no controller ou view, caso contrário não enviaria para o Gmail, mas se precisar eu posto sim.
Spam conferido em todas as vezes e endereço não está no spam;
Mais uma vez, muito obrigado pela Ajuda. 
Está 100x melhor que o próprio suporte da BlueHost Brasil.